# Alternatives to isGranted in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, roles

While testing roles in my application I found the function `isGranted` of the `SecurityContext`. It works great but now I need to check the roles of a user that is not the current user so `isGranted` doesn't work for me.

I've been looking and I found the function `hasRole` of the user, the problem is that this function doesn't look in the hierarchy tree of Symfony and it just looks in the roles assigned to the user.

So, Is there a function that looks for a role of a user looking in the hierarchy tree like `isGranted` do for the current user?

EDIT

I found this solution:

[How to use the AccessDecisionManager in Symfony2 for authorization of arbitrary users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288293/how-to-use-the-accessdecisionmanager-in-symfony2-for-authorization-of-arbitrary)

I implemented it and it works, the problem is that it needs the `ContainerBuilder` and I would prefer a different approach.

Any Idea?

Comment: Your roles should be stocked in your database so you can just make a request to get the role of a different user than the one witch is connected (sorry i don't know if there is a method for this, it's just another idea to resolve your problem)

Comment: I have a list of users and depending on the roles of the user the actions that can be applied vary

Answer (score 0):

Basically AFAIK SecurityContext work with `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface` from where can fetch current user using `getUser` method.

If user token is not authenticated then `isGranted` trying authenticate user token first and then use class called `AccessDecisionManager` which basically iterate over voters objects and call them (and can use different strategies for that) One of called voters is `RoleHierarchyVoter` which use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy`.

So answer to your question:

I think that is no such function like isGranted for other users (or do not know about any), but you can write own service which allow to that using `security.role_hierarchy` (just notice that is private service).

BTW `hasRole` probably should be sufficient most of the time, so maybe you should think about what do you want to do ;)

Comment: Hi l3l0, the function hasRole is not sufficient because I need to look in the hierarchy tree.

Comment: Hello @graffiacaneif you using FOSUserBundle you have such method as getRoles which should returns all user roles see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L312 and Model/User::hasRole should work with it too

Comment: Hi l3L0, maybe I'm not explaining well, but these functions doesn't return the roles that a user have inherited from the hierarchy tree, just the ones associated to the user in the database.

Comment: Indeed l3l0 that was my first approach, and my conclussions were the same as the ones that Adrian gets in the solution I mention in my question.