# Check if a role is granted for a specific user in Symfony2 ACL

Tags: symfony, acl

I want to check if a role is granted for a specific user in Symfony2 (not the logged user).
I know that I can check it for the logged user by:

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('VIEW', $objectIdentity)) {
        //do anything
}
```

but if I'm the logged user and I wand to check other user if **isGranted** ??

Answer (score 6):

The "VIEW" is a permission, not a role.

The best way to check if a user has a right (be it a role or permission) would be to access the AccessDecisionManager. Something like:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'none', 'none', $user->getRoles());
$attributes = is_array($attributes) ? $attributes : array($attributes);
$this->get('security.access.decision_manager')->decide($token, $attributes, $object);
```

See original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380765/971254 for details.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Access Control Lists are way too complicated for common use cases.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to create a custom security context that will take a user object and generate a UserSecurityIdentity out of it. Here are the steps:

Create a new service in YourApp/AppBundle/Resources/config.yml

```
yourapp.security_context:
    class: YourApp\AppBundle\Security\Core\SecurityContext
    arguments: [ @security.acl.provider ]
```

Create a custom Security Context Class like this:

```
namespace YourApp\AppBundle\Security\Core;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\MutableAclProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\NoAceFoundException;

use YourApp\AppBundle\Document\User;

/**
 * Allows ACL checking against a specific user object (regardless of whether that user is logged in or not)
 *
 */
class SecurityContext
{
    public function __construct(MutableAclProviderInterface $aclProvider)
    {
        $this->aclProvider = $aclProvider;
    }

    public function isGranted($mask, $object, User $user)
    {
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($object);
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        try {
            $acl = $this->aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity, array($securityIdentity));
        } catch (AclNotFoundException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!is_int($mask)) {
            $builder = new MaskBuilder;
            $builder->add($mask);

            $mask = $builder->get();
        }

        try {
            return $acl->isGranted(array($mask), array($securityIdentity), false);
        } catch (NoAceFoundException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can inject that service where needed, or use it from a controller like this:

```php
$someUser = $this->findSomeUserFromYourDatabase();

if ($this->get('yourapp.security_context')->isGranted('VIEW', $article, $someUser) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking roles for another user can not be done via the `SecurityContext` as this will always hold the current user's session token. Your task can be achieved for example via the `getRoles` method, if the user you need to check implements the `UserInterface`.

```
$otherUser = $this->get('doctrine')->...   // fetch the user

if( $otherUser instanceof \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface  )
{ 
     $roles = $otherUser->getRoles();

     // your role could be VIEW or ROLE_VIEW, check the $roles array above. 
     if ( in_array( 'VIEW' , $roles ) )
     {
      // do something else
     }
}
```

If your user entity implement the ***`FosUserBundle`*** `UserInterFace`, that has a dedicated method `hasRole`. In that case you could use a one-liner:

```
$otherUser = $this->get('doctrine')->...   // fetch the user

if( $otherUser instanceof \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface  )
{ 
     // your role could be VIEW or ROLE_VIEW, check the proper role names
     if ( $otherUser->hasRole( 'VIEW' ) )
     {
      // do something else
     }
}
```

Comment: No, I want something like this: $user = $em->getRepository('ZxZZBundle:User')->find($id);
        if(false === $user->isGranted('VIEW', $objectIdentity) ) {
            // xxxxx
        }
        but User not have isGranted method.

Comment: I want to check if he has "VIEW" role on specific entity, for example I want to check if user3 can view Product entity or user2 can create Product entity.

Comment: What kind of mechanism are you using to keep track of these ACL definitions?

Comment: Note that `in_array()` & `hasRole()` don't take into account the ROLE inheritance